# Recursive function to find binary not returning elements in single array. (Not pushing to the same )

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Problem statement: I'm trying to get string > binary without using the inbuilt method in javascript.

This is a piece of program where a string input (like "ABC") is accepted, then it is translated to an array of equivalent code value ([65,66,67]).

Function binary() will change a number to binary. But I'm unable to join them together to loop through all the contents. Please help. (I'm a noob, please forgive my bad code and bad explanation)

```js
var temp3 = [65,66,67];
var temp2 = [];
var r;

for(i=0;i<temp3.length;i++) {
var  r = temp3[i];    
temp2.push(binary(r));
}

function binary(r) {
  if (r === 0) return;
  temp2.unshift(r % 2);
  binary(Math.floor(r / 2));
  return temp2;
}
console.log(temp2);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I took the liberty of moving you example code into a snippet.  However, it does not run-- it looks like you have a syntax error at `tempstring.forEach(items)` where you are most likely meaning to be passing a function callback.  Please fix your example code so it executes, and then it will be easier to provide you with additional guidance.

Comment: Alex, thank you for helping me. I'm facing trouble with joining for loop and function binary. Getting an error (Maximum call stack size exceeded) here when combined. These codes works individually. I hope this helps!

Comment: The value that returns from the recursive `binary` call isn't used, so there's no way your recursion will move forward - nothing changes between its calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a cleaner version of this function.  It should work for any non-negative integers, and would be easy enough to extend to the negatives.  If we have a single binary digit (`0` or `1`) and hence are less than `2`, we just return the number converted to a string.  Otherwise we call recursively on the floor of half the number (as yours does) and append the final digit.

```js
const binary = (n) =>
  n < 2
    ? String (n)
    : binary (Math.floor (n / 2)) + (n % 2)
    
console.log (binary(22)) //=> '10110'

console.log ([65, 66, 67] .map (binary)) //=> ['1000001', '1000010', '1000011']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function you have this code

```
var  r = temp3[i];
```

I don't see any `temp3` variable anywhere in your code above so I'd imagine that could be causing some issues.

Comment: Thank you, Optiq! It was a wrong code (Updated it now). I am getting the code as above. getting correct output as below: